# Proceed next input when press enter and ignore if there are hidden input

Tags: jquery

I have here a function script when the user press enter it will move to next element. My problem here was the hidden element causes my script not to continue to next field because the next element is hidden.

How to ignore the input/element if is hidden?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#civil_status').keyup(function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    if (status == '2') {
      $('#civilstatus_div').css('display', '');
      $('#spouse_name').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#civilstatus_div').css('display', 'none');
      $('#spouse_name').attr('disabled', true);
      $("#spouse_name").val('');
    }
  });
});

$("input, select, textarea").not($(":button")).keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    iname = $(this).val();
    if (iname !== 'Submit') {
      var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button, input, textarea, select, hidden');
      var index = fields.index(this);
      if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {
        fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="civil_status"><small><b>CIVIL STATUS:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <center>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="civil_status" id="civil_status" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mr-4">
      <span><small>&nbsp;1-Single, 2-Married, 3-Widowed, 4-Separated</small></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-1" style="display:none;" id="civilstatus_div">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-0">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="spouse_name"><small><b>NAME OF SPOUSE<br>IF MARRIED:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-3">
    <center>
      <span id="spouse_hidden"></span>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="spouse_name" id="spouse_name" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-0">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="mainden_name"><small><b>MOTHER'S<br>MAIDEN NAME:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-3">
    <center>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="mainden_name" id="mainden_name" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's my working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/pl11/zs69afh1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue you simply need to exclude the hidden elements from those you select in the `fields` variable. To do this use `.not()`.

Also note that the selector you're using to find the fields can be shortened to just `:input`.

```
var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find(':input').not(':hidden');
```

In addition, your second function is outside the document.ready handler. You need to correct the braces and parentheses around this function.

Working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#civil_status').keyup(function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    let shouldEnable = this.value.trim() === '2';
    $('#civilstatus_div').toggle(shouldEnable);
    $('#spouse_name').prop('disabled', !shouldEnable).val('');
  });

  $("input, select, textarea").not($(":button")).keypress(function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
      iname = $(this).val();
      if (iname !== 'Submit') {
        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find(':input').not(':hidden');
        var index = fields.index(this);
        if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {
          fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="civil_status"><small><b>CIVIL STATUS:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <center>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="civil_status" id="civil_status" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mr-4">
      <span><small>&nbsp;1-Single, 2-Married, 3-Widowed, 4-Separated</small></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-1" style="display:none;" id="civilstatus_div">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-0">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="spouse_name"><small><b>NAME OF SPOUSE<br>IF MARRIED:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-3">
    <center>
      <span id="spouse_hidden"></span>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="spouse_name" id="spouse_name" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-0">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="mainden_name"><small><b>MOTHER'S<br>MAIDEN NAME:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-3">
    <center>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="mainden_name" id="mainden_name" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- this will be ignored -->
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-0">
    <label class="float-left col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="mainden_name"><small><b>FOO'S<br>MAIDEN NAME:</b></small></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mt-3">
    <center>
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-11" name="mainden_name" id="foo" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase; outline: 0;text-align:center;">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, it would make a *lot* more sense if the first `input` was a `select`. Then you're not relying on people to type the right number

Comment: Wow! Thanks for quick response sir!

Comment: Can I ask another question regarding on this question?

Comment: Glad to help. Sure, although if it's an in-depth request I'd suggest starting a new question

Comment: Just a little addition, the script not continuing to a append input. But I will start a new question if its not allowed here. Thanks!